# Are relations same as table?

Tags: database, database-relations

I am taking database course and came across the term relation. Are relations same as tables and can be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "relation" is another word for table.

Personally I don't like this term because it is likely to be confused with "relationship", which is an association between two tables.